# Font-size is not working on Opera and Chrome, but works on Firefox, thouh other parameters are working

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size, opera

Font-size is not working on Opera and Chrome, but works on Firefox. Works borders, margins, animations, sizes,font family, but not the font-size.

I have a complicated ul-li navigation in nested spans. I am not able to set the font size on inner `<a>`. I did not set fonts on other parts/elements yet, except the `html - 16px`.  I tried rem and px units, none is workign in Opera and Chrome. Is there a special way to set font-size for deep nested elements? Why other rules are working?

```
<div> <span>..12 spans... <span> 
   <a class='a.aBtn' ><span class='navDecr' ></span></a>
   ...other 12 <a> tags ...
   <ul> <li></li> ...12 li ... </ul> 
 </span> ... 12 closing spans </div>

//the same error a.aBtn span.navDescr {}

a span.navDescr { 
    font : 2rem, "Open Sans", sans-serif !important; //this is stroked through 
    text-align: right;
    text-align-last:left;
    font-weight:normal; 
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height : 1.5; //will be multiplied with font_size
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-size-adjust:1;
}
```

If i try to put font on `li` items children, it also does not work. Works borders, margins, animations, sizes,font family, but not the font-size.

Comment: Have you tried separating font-size and font-family?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `font-size` if you want to change the size of a font and `font-family` to change it to another font

Change from

```
<a class='a.aBtn' ><span class='navDecr' >Test</span></a>

a span.navDescr { 
    font : 2rem, "Open Sans", sans-serif !important; //this is stroked through 
    text-align: right;
    text-align-last:left;
    font-weight:normal; 
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height : 1.5; //will be multiplied with font_size
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-size-adjust:1;
}
```

To

```
<a class='aBtn' ><span class='navDecr' >Test</span></a>

.aBtn span { 
    font-size : 2rem; 
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important; //this is stroked through
    text-align: right;
    text-align-last:left;
    font-weight:normal; 
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height : 1.5; //will be multiplied with font_size
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-size-adjust:1;
}
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

Seems the reason is in some of other font rules.
Finally, find out that "line-height" rules makes font-size not to work in Opera and Chrome browsers. 
I mean complicated structure is not related to the problem.

```
a.aBtn span.navDescr, a.aBtn span.navDescr p {
    font-family : "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
    font-size : $aBtnFontSize !important;
    text-align: right;
    text-align-last:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style:normal;
    //font_size : 3rem !important;
    // line-height : 1.5; //opera ignores : MAKES THIS ERROR 
    font-stretch: normal; 
    font-size-adjust:1; 
}
```